# qml compatibility for touch,touch n type and type devices

Tags: qml

i am new to Qt.i am going to develop an app for symbian "touch,touch n type and only type" devices
my question is that how can i write my qml compatible for these three??compatibility like navigation resolution etc.i will be happy to get answer of this.

Regards

Adnan Shoukat

Answer (score 0):

If you plan develop using QML on Symbian you can address only touch and touch&type devices. Type only (Symbian S60.3) devices basically do not support QML - you can run QML app on them but there is no official support and you will not be able to publish your app.

There are only two resolutions for Symbian: 640x360 and 640x480 (for some specific Nokia E? model). Write resolution independent app and forget about resolution.